# Next/Previous Links in same category

Tags: pagination, navigation

I've been pouring over this problem that seems really minor, but I can't seem to solve it. I'm trying to make next/previous links that only link to the category that the post is in. This is for a custom post type called portfolio. This is the code I currently have on the content-portfolio page:

```
<?php next_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous">%link</div>', '<span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '←', 'Next post link', 'morphology' ) . '</span> %title'); ?>
<?php previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>', '%title <span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '→', 'Previous post link', 'morphology' ) . '</span>'); ?>
```

I've seen some variations of the following, but I can't seem to edit it to get it to cooperate:

```
<?php next_post_link( '%link', 'Next post in category', TRUE ); ?>
```

Any advice as to how to make this work or what I'm doing wrong?

---

Update:
I still haven't gotten a good solution to this, and nothing I've tried from the other top Google hits seem to be working. As soon as I say that in_same_term = true, the link disappears entirely. Based on the answer below, this is the code I'm using:

```
<?php next_post_link( 
'<div class="nav-previous">%link</div>', 
'<span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '←', 'Next post link', 'morphology' ) . '</span> %title', true, array(), 'portfolio'); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

[`previous_post_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link) takes 5 params, but you use only 2 of them.

Let's take a look at other 3:

> - **in_same_term** *(boolean) (optional)* Indicates whether previous post must
>     be within the same taxonomy term as the current post. If set to
>     'true', only posts from the current taxonomy term will be displayed.
>     If the post is in both the parent and subcategory, or more than one
>     term, the previous post link will lead to the previous post in any of
>     those terms. true false Default: false
> - **excluded_terms** *(string/array)*
>     (optional) Array or a comma-separated list of numeric terms IDs from
>     which the next post should not be listed. For example array(1, 5) or
>     '1,5'. This argument used to accept a list of IDs separated by 'and',
>     this was deprecated in WordPress 3.3 Default: None
> - **taxonomy** *(string)
>     (Optional)* Taxonomy, if $in_same_term is true. Added in WordPress 3.8.
>     Default: 'category'

So if you want to navigate through posts from the same category, third param should be set to true.

```
<?php
    previous_post_link(
        '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>',
        '%title <span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '→', 'Previous post link', 'morphology' ) . '</span>',
         true
    );
?>
```

And if your portfolio uses custom taxonomy, you should point that out in last param:

```
<?php
    previous_post_link(
        '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>',
        '%title <span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '→', 'Previous post link', 'morphology' ) . '</span>',
         true,
         array(),
         'my_custom_taxonomy'
    );
?>
```

It works the same with `next_post_link`.

Comment: First, I really appreciate you laying things out for me. That was really helpful in understanding how this works. I'm still learning PHP and sometimes I run into these things I just don't quite get. Unfortunately, the suggestion didn't work. I'm not using custom taxonomy, just categories within the custom post type. It looks like array() is param #4 without any input, though shouldn't #4 and #5 be optional? When I end after true, it breaks the site. Otherwise though the links just don't show.

Comment: So this is the code that I'm using. When #3 is marked as true, nothing appears. When it's marked as false the links show up, but obviously not restricted to the current category: <?php
   previous_post_link(
   '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>',
   '%title <span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '→', 'Previous post link', 'morphology' ) . '</span>',
   false,
   array(),
   'category'
  ); ?>